# powershell script to move/copy files from network path to SharePoint sub folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}




        $spWeb=Get-SPWeb -identity "http://sharepoint.contoso.com/Corporate/Sales/"
        $spFolder =$spWeb.GetFolder("arizona")
        $spFileCollection =$spFolder.Files

        Get-ChildItem "\Daily Reports\arizona\" -filter "*.xlsx" | ForEach {
         $spFileCollection.Add("arizona/$($_.Name)",$_.OpenRead(),$true)
                    }

$web.Dispose()
```

My problem is arizona is not the top level folder but is under shared documents which is the top level document library.

How do I go about adding documents to my arizona folder from my network directory?

Comment: how to add the part to parse the title of the received documents ?

Comment: i need a powershell script to move/copy files from network path to SharePoint library . i dont have any folders inside. where to change the above script ?
suppose if i want to move to this location only "Shared Documents"
Please share ASAP

Comment: Can we do opposite? SharePoint Document Library to File Share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this powershell to upload to specific folder.

```
  if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
    {
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
    }

    #Script settings

    $webUrl = "http://sharepoint.contoso.com/Corporate/Sales/"

    $docLibraryName = "Shared Documents"
    $docLibraryUrlName = "Shared Documents\arizona"    # specify your subfolder url here

    $localFolderPath = "C:\Test"

    #Open web and library

    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    write-host $webUrl

    $docLibrary = $web.Lists[$docLibraryName]
    write-host $docLibrary

    $files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item $localFolderPath)).GetFiles()

    write-host $files

    ForEach($file in $files)
    {

if($file.Name.Contains(".pdf"))
{
    write-host $file

        #Open file
        try
        {
        $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()

        #Add file
        $folder =  $web.getfolder($docLibraryUrlName)

        write-host "Copying file " $file.Name " to " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl "..."
        $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name,[System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
        write-host "Success"

        #Close file stream
        $fileStream.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        Write "Error: $file.name: $_" >>c:\logfile.txt
            continue;
        }
}
    }

    #Dispose web

    $web.Dispose()
```

this will add your files from local drive to Arizona folder from network drive c:/Test

Comment: You can also use Robocopy or a simple file copy with powershell and create the path of the document library. And then just copy from shared path to Sharepoint Shared Path. Looks like `\\sharepoint-server@20502(portnumber of web app)\DavWWWRoot\sites\site-example\document-library` and you can `net use` this path, and copy/paste. Don't forget to `net use ... /DELETE`.

Comment: I want to just upload certain type of files although there are different type of files in that folder . eg I want to upload all *.docx or *.doc , how do i do that

Comment: see my update answer. just replace .pdf with type  of extension you want. also if you want more than one extension , than just use "-or" in the if loop

Answer (score 3):

When adding files using PowerShell I prefer using Invoke-WebRequest with the PUT verb and then just specify the URL to where you want to store the file and its name.

Comment: @Ashish I want to just upload certain type of files although there are different type of files in that folder . eg I want to upload all *.docx  or *.doc , how do i do that